# Flash Notice on Ajax Success Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to get a flash message in my html page under some conditions. I'm new to Ruby and i don't know how to make this work.

this is my controller

```
     if @item_point > current_user.points
        flash[:alert] = "You don't have enough points to buy this item"
      else
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to '/hhr'}
        format.js
      end
```

and in my script i'm trying to get it in my ajax success function.. But i'm not able to get it .. Is there any way i can get this flash message in my jquery function or in my view.
pls help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Post your `script code`

Comment: Add relevant script and Html code, where you want to display flash message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code. it might help you

```
#inside your rails controller method  
flash[:notice] = "Your Notice content to be displayed"



#rails helper
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_notifications
    message = flash[:error] || flash[:notice]

    if message
      type = flash.keys[0].to_s
      javascript_tag %Q{$.notification({ message:"#{message}", type:"#{type}" });}
    end
  end

end



#rails layout
<%= flash_notifications -%>



#javascript code
(function( $, undefined ) {
    $.notification = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, {type: 'notice', time: 3000}, options);
        var o    = opts;

        timeout          = setTimeout('$.notification.removebar()', o.time);
        var message_span = $('<span />').addClass('jbar-content').html(o.message);
        var wrap_bar     = $('<div />').addClass('jbar jbar-top').css("cursor", "pointer");

    if (o.type == 'error') {
          wrap_bar.css({"color": "#D8000C"})
        };

        wrap_bar.click(function(){
            $.notification.removebar()
        });

        wrap_bar.append(message_span).hide()
            .insertBefore($('.container')).fadeIn('fast');
    };


    var timeout;
    $.notification.removebar    = function(txt) {
        if($('.jbar').length){
            clearTimeout(timeout);

            $('.jbar').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }   
    };


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this:

[Jquery AJAX: How to display the Flash error message when validation on the server side fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957641/jquery-ajax-how-to-display-the-flash-error-message-when-validation-on-the-serve)

It recommends to return an HTML error status from your Rails app and then you can add your flash[:alert] in the Ajax 'error' callback.